# I got Maximum recursion depth exceeded on this code

Tags: python

```
#Smallest window to get a string

from collections import Counter

def smallestWin(str1):
    # make a short set contain all character
    tableOfChar = {}
    setOfallCharacter = {chars for chars in Counter(str1)}
    for i in range(len(str1)-len(setOfallCharacter)+1):
         windowChar = makeWindow(str1[i:i+len(setOfallCharacter)-1],setOfallCharacter)
         tableOfChar[len(windowChar)] = windowChar
    print(windowChar)

def makeWindow(str1,remainLimChar):
        # Len of limit char
        lenRemain = len(remainLimChar)                                    
        if lenRemain <= 0:
            return "" 
        
        baseString = str1[:lenRemain-1]
        setOfallCharacter = {chars for chars in Counter(baseString)}
        charRemain = setOfallCharacter ^ remainLimChar

        return baseString + makeWindow(str1[lenRemain:],charRemain)         

def main():
    str1 = "asdaewsqgtwwsa"
    smallestWin(str1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this code is about: Write a Python program to find the smallest window that contains all characters in a given string and i use recursion solve it. i use recursion to remove all character base on len of total character need to find. ex: if total character need to fill in window is 8 so i need to find how many character that i got in range (:8-1). if i found 5/8. then i keep finding till len = 0.

Comment: Does this have to be recursion? It's very unconventional to do it this way. A sliding window is the norm.

Comment: I use Bitwise Operators: for 2 sets of character to find the remain character list that i need to find next.

Ex: setOfallCharacter = {"a","b","c"}
remainLimChar = {"a","b"}
=> charRemain = {"c"} => this i remain chacter that i need to find next on my recursion

Comment: To add on @SimonT: Unless specified in the task, recursion can ALWAYS be replaced by a while loop. Recursion is merely a way you can do this and may be easier in some cases. However, if you get stuck with recursion, don't just push on but consider another way of doing this..

Comment: @SimonT i try to practise with recursion and i think this way can reduce time complexity

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Yes. Maybe if i can't find any answer about this way, ill try another way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I personally would do this, if recursion is not required

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def smallest_window(s: str) -> str:
    if not s:
        return ""

    unique_chars = set(s)
    unique_chars_count = len(unique_chars)

    char_count: dict[str, int] = defaultdict(int)
    start, min_len, min_start = 0, float('inf'), 0
    unique_counter = 0

    for end in range(len(s)):
        char_count[s[end]] += 1
        if char_count[s[end]] == 1:
            unique_counter += 1

        while unique_counter == unique_chars_count:
            if end - start < min_len:
                min_len = end - start
                min_start = start

            char_count[s[start]] -= 1
            if char_count[s[start]] == 0:
                unique_counter -= 1
            start += 1

    return "" if min_len == float('inf') else s[min_start:min_start + min_len + 1]

def main():
    str1 = "asdaewsqgtwwsa"
    print(smallest_window(str1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

511 ns ± 3.48 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

To keep using your counter method

```py
from collections import Counter


def smallest_window(s: str) -> str:
    if not s:
        return ""

    char_set = set(s)
    char_counter: dict[str, int] = Counter()

    start = 0
    min_length = float("inf")
    min_window = ""

    for end in range(len(s)):
        char_counter[s[end]] += 1

        while all(char_counter[c] > 0 for c in char_set):
            window_length = end - start + 1
            if window_length < min_length:
                min_length = window_length
                min_window = s[start : end + 1]

            char_counter[s[start]] -= 1
            start += 1

    return min_window


def main():
    str1 = "asdaewsqgtwwsa"
    print(smallest_window(str1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

533 ns ± 1.58 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

If you really had to use recursion you can do something like this, which retains the order of the substr

```py
from collections import Counter


def find_smallest_window_recursive(
    s: str,
    start: int,
    end: int,
    unique_chars: set[str],
    current_window: str,
    min_window: str,
) -> str:
    if end == len(s):
        return min_window

    current_window = s[start : end + 1]
    window_counter = Counter(current_window)

    if any(window_counter[char] <= 0 for char in unique_chars):
        return find_smallest_window_recursive(
            s, start, end + 1, unique_chars, current_window, min_window
        )
    if len(current_window) < len(min_window):
        min_window = current_window
    return find_smallest_window_recursive(
        s, start + 1, end, unique_chars, current_window, min_window
    )


def smallest_window(s: str) -> str:
    if not s:
        return ""

    unique_chars = set(s)
    return find_smallest_window_recursive(s, 0, 0, unique_chars, "", s)


def main():
    str1 = "asdaewsqgtwwsa"
    print(smallest_window(str1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

817 ns ± 7.83 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

Comment: oh i see. Thank you so much!!! @SimonT